# Run jQuery in Windows' desktop

Tags: javascript, jquery, windows, windows-7, windows-desktop-gadgets

What I'm trying to accomblish here is run a very simple jQuery script inside my Windows 7 desktop background.

Some time ago I would just go on and use the `Active Desktop` gadget which would allow me to set any web page as my desktop background just by configuring it with the web page's URL. Unfortunately Microsoft has discontinued gadgets: http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/gadgets, so what would be a good way to run a jQuery script (which changes the background color based on the current time) or a simple HTML page containing that script?

Edit: This is how I would do it some time ago: http://www.bustatech.com/display-a-webpage-on-desktop-window-vista-and-window-7/

Comment: You should look into something like a Windows Forms Application. Your request is not possible using JavaScript/jQuery just like SLaks said. Maybe you're not explaining what you want correctly...

Comment: Thanks guys for your comments, I have updated my answer to include an example of how I would do it if Windows Gadgets would have not been discontinued by Microsoft: http://www.bustatech.com/display-a-webpage-on-desktop-window-vista-and-window-7/

Comment: Ok... I see where you're going...I think. I would still look into using .net to develop something like that can run on your desktop. You don't need JavaScript or jQuery unless you're wanting build out a custom web site. There's actually controls in .NET such as the WebBrowser control that allow you to give it a URL and it will navigate to it. However, your question requires you to first develop the widget, then you can start to continue down the web page path. Simply using HTML/JavaScript/jQuery/CSS will not work for what you want to do. You need .NET to make it work on a desktop